# Argument 3 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\LayerCategoryConfig

Tags: plugin, magento2.4

I have plugin that works fine in magento 2.3 but in magento 2.4 i am getting below error :

**Argument 3 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\LayerCategoryConfig, array given Shopby/Model/Layer/FilterList.php on line 77**

code of filterlist.php as below :

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Amasty\Shopby\Model\Source\VisibleInCategory;

class FilterList extends Layer\FilterList
{
    const PLACE_SIDEBAR = 'sidebar';
    const PLACE_TOP     = 'top';
    const ALL_FILTERS_KEY     = 'amasty_shopby_all_filters';

    /**
     * @var \Amasty\Shopby\Helper\FilterSetting\Proxy
     */
    private $filterSetting;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $currentPlace;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $filtersLoaded  = false;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $filtersMatched = false;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $filtersApplied = false;

    /**
     * @var  \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface $filterableAttributes,
        \Amasty\Shopby\Helper\FilterSetting\Proxy $filterSettingHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $filters = [],
        $place = self::PLACE_SIDEBAR
    ) {
        $this->currentPlace = $place;
        $this->filterSetting = $filterSettingHelper;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($objectManager, $filterableAttributes, $filters);
    }
```

Error is on line  **parent::__construct($objectManager, $filterableAttributes, $filters);**

Please help with what we need to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent construct has been changed in Magento 2.4 version as below

```
/**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param FilterableAttributeListInterface $filterableAttributes
     * @param LayerCategoryConfig $layerCategoryConfig
     * @param array $filters
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        FilterableAttributeListInterface $filterableAttributes,
        LayerCategoryConfig $layerCategoryConfig,
        array $filters = []
    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->filterableAttributes = $filterableAttributes;
        $this->layerCategoryConfig = $layerCategoryConfig;

        /** Override default filter type models */
        $this->filterTypes = array_merge($this->filterTypes, $filters);
    }
```

In your parent construct you need to pass dependency to parent as below. Change your construct code same as below

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface $filterableAttributes,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\LayerCategoryConfig $layerCategoryConfig,
        \Amasty\Shopby\Helper\FilterSetting\Proxy $filterSettingHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $filters = [],
        $place = self::PLACE_SIDEBAR
    ) {
        $this->currentPlace = $place;
        $this->filterSetting = $filterSettingHelper;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($objectManager, $filterableAttributes, $layerCategoryConfig, $filters);
    }
```